# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Api' not found

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. When I tried to run the below code getting the following error.

**Error Message:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Api' not found in C:\Users\cpa\Downloads\b\vendor\php1.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\cpa\Downloads\b\vendor\php1.php on line 4
```

Api.php is there in the following location. I tried n different ways to include the class but no luck. Please let me know how to resolve this error message.

C:\Users\cpa\Downloads\b\vendor\brightlocal\api\src\BrightLocal

Code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/brightlocal/api/src/BrightLocal/Api.php';

$api = new Api('key', 'secret_key');

// get a list of clients
print_r($api->call('/v2/clients/get-all'));

// get a client
print_r($api->call('/v2/clients/get', array(
    'client-id' => 1059
)));

// get LSRC report list
print_r($api->call('/v2/lsrc/get-all'));

// get LSRC report
print_r($api->call('/v2/lsrc/get', array(
    'campaign-id' => 50
)));

// get CT report list
print_r($api->call('/v2/ct/get-all'));

// get a CT report
print_r($api->call('/v2/ct/get', array(
    'report-id' => 259
)));
```

Comment: Can you share your `Api.php` file

Comment: also try `require ./BrightLocal/Api.php`

Comment: where do you keep `api.php` ? describe folder structure of your files

Comment: php1.php is there in C:\Users\cpa8161\Downloads\b\vendor.

Comment: don't you think you shoud do this : `require 'brightlocal/api/src/BrightLocal/Api.php`

Comment: api.php code is in the following location: https://github.com/BrightLocal/BrightLocal-API-Helper/tree/master/src/BrightLocal

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that are a bit off:

- Why are you in the vendor folder? This things is actually used for external libraries that you download via composer or where you place the autoloader.
- The require (why not require_once ?) is in the wrong folder. As can be seen from the error message. My suggestion is that you move the frontcontroller (php1.php) out of the vendor folder and in the folder which has the vendor folder as a subfolder: C:\Users\cpa\Downloads\b and setup your system from there anew.

  require 'vendor/brightlocal/api/src/BrightLocal/Api.php';

Comment: Folder Structure :                                                                                     
cd c/Users/cpa/Downloads/b
composer.json  composer.lock  php1.php  vendor
./vendor:
autoload.php  brightlocal  composer  guzzlehttp  php1.php  psr
./vendor/brightlocal:
api
./vendor/brightlocal/api:
composer.json  Examples  README.md  src
./vendor/brightlocal/api/src:
BrightLocal  php1.php
./vendor/brightlocal/api/src/BrightLocal:
Api.php  Batches
./vendor/brightlocal/api/src/BrightLocal/Batches:
V1.php  V4.php

Comment: I tried as you mentioned above but no luck. I gave the folder structure in  above comment.

Comment: What about echoing the current working directory with `echo getcwd();` and continuing your work from there. This way you see what PHP thinks where you are.